# Partial borders in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, border, styling

Is it possible to apply partial borders (e.g. a border on only the right-hand edge, or on only the top and the bottom) to an element in Python Tkinter?

EDIT: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux3eU.jpg) is the layout I'm trying to achieve - if anyone can see a better way of achieving this than partial borders, please feel free to point it out - I'm not very experienced with Tkinter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on what you mean by "borders". Individual widgets have borders (buttons, etc), and for those you can't change just part of the border.

If instead you're asking about how to layout your widgets so that there are dividing lines between them, you can do this with the `padx` and `pady` options of `grid` and `pack`. For those you can have different amounts of padding on each edge.

Comment: Great, thank you for this! I've set the background colour of my main containing frame to black, and am getting the desired outlines by putting padding between the child frames. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to this built in to tkinter, but why do you need this behaviour? There is probably a better way to accomplish what you need. See this [this resource](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/229211/tkinter#) for more help with your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the resource - I think that will allow me to achieve the end result I'm looking for, though it's a shame there's no "cleaner" way of doing it that doesn't require extra elements.

Comment: @scubbo: you can achieve that sort of layout without having to change the borders of the widget. Borders are a different thing than the space _between_ the widgets.